# Gallery permission and Camera Permission not working

Tags: android, camera, android-permissions, android-gallery, user-permissions

i was adding profile picture option in my application from camera and gallery All was working well till i tried to select a picture and display it in my image circulerView .when i select a picture to set in my imageCirculerView , it doesn't set in the imageCirculerView and no error is even showing ..So i literally don't know where i did the mistake

```
private void pickFromGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"select picture"), IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE);
    }

    private void pickFromCamera() {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Temp_image Title");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Temp_desc Desctription");
        image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);

    }


      profilepicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //pick a image
                    showImagePickDialog();
                }
            });
      private void showImagePickDialog() {
            //options to display in dialoge
            String[] options = {"Camera", "Dialoge"};
            //dialoge
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Pick Image").setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == 0) {
                        //Camera Clicked
                        if (checkCameraPermission()) {
                            //Camera request allowed
                            pickFromCamera();
                        } else {
                            //not allowed Request
                            requestCameraPermission();
                        }
                    } else {
                        //gallery Clicked
                        if (checkStoragePermission()) {
                            //Storage request allowed
                            pickFromGallery();
                        } else {
                            //not allowed Request
                            requestStoragePermission();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).show();
        }
     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            if(requestCode == RESULT_OK){
                if(requestCode== IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE){
                    //getPicked image
                    image_uri = data.getData();
                    //settoimageView
                    profilepicture.setImageURI(image_uri);
                }else if(requestCode== IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE){
                    //settoimageView
                    profilepicture.setImageURI(image_uri);}
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete to answer . `if(requestCode == RESULT_OK)` this wrong inside `onActivityResult` it should be `if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)` .. On a side note if you face any more problem follow some tutorial cause this is something you can learn better from tutorial as its an essential part of Android development ..

Comment: Thank u .This helped .. I did a poor mistake ..Thank u so muuch for the help